# SSL Security Clarifications

Tags: php, html, mysql, ssl, https

If I have a domain: `https://somedomain.example` with a valid SSL certificate do I have to take any other precautions to encrypt data between clients and my server, or is my only concern now to protect data on the server via some AES encryption in my MySQL database.

Essentially, do I leave all of the security between client and server down to SSL, is that how Facebook and Google do it for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using SSL will handle all the encryption so the data will be protected *in transit*.

Authentication, authorisation and defences against [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) and [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) need handling separately. (Although you *can* use SSL client certs for authentication).

XSS is something to watch out for in particular, if an attacker can inject JS into the page, then it can access the data in the browser where (unlike when it is in transit) it isn't encrypted.

Comment: I think you answered my question yesterday as well haha. I'll read into both of those, at first glance it looks very complex. Would this type of vulnerability still exist if I was simply using Javascript to handle animations, ajax requests to php? Quote from your links: `occur anywhere a web application uses input from a user in the output it generates without validating or encoding it.` If I had my Javascript encrypt the users client side input before it was sent with SHA1 or something, and it retrieves a key via the server through SSL wouldn't that still be very vulernable?

Comment: `-Continued comment because I ran out of space-` For instance the second the key comes back from the server to encrypt client side, the key would have to be decryption at some point, and if it wasn't it would be a key itself - someone could easily view it then. It seems that this type of vulnerability is for output generated from user input, but I am simply handling information such as username, password, email, message boards (for arguments sake lets say like Stack Overflow) and a Wiki. Forgive me if I am jumping the gun on my very small knowledge of XSS/CSRF gained in the past 5 minutes :)

Comment: You can't use client side code to protect against XSS (stored XSS in particular). Your control over the data starts when it reaches your server, before then it is a free for all.

Comment: So really I should have a set of instructions outlining the type of information I can accept, and all other information is denied? A whitelist.

Comment: Message boards are particularly vulnerable to XSS and CSRF. The former because they are often accepting *formatted* user input, which usually means HTML, which means lots of places that an attacker could potentially inject JS (intrinsic event attributes, style attributes, script elements, URIs) and CSRF (because you have user accounts, and are storing submitted data).

Comment: If you need to accept HTML, then you need to whitelist it. (If you aren't using HTML then you can usually get away with just escaping it). e.g. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.236_-_Use_an_HTML_Policy_engine_to_validate_or_clean_user-driven_HTML_in_an_outbound_way

Comment: I planned on using a system similar to Stack Overflow, ** for bold, as an example - and based on that special delimiter "**" the server then generates the appropriate HTML when sending information back. This owasp looks like a very good resource so I'll be sure to give everything you're linking an extensive read.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you mean but even with SSL it's a good idea to use password salts in the database. There's no good reason for you to store plain text passwords in your database. Even if the data stored on your servers isn't all that sensitive since users typically use the same password across sites if your database is compromised you may be giving out the password to something serious like their online banking.

Personally I prefer to take it a step farther and implement a challenge response scheme on top of salting passwords. It's pretty easy to implement and that way my server rarely ever sees the user's actual password with the exception of during sign up. In my opinion, the less my server knows, the better.

Comment: I never had any intention of storing plain text passwords ever, I was always going to encrypt them using some form of AES via MySQL. Thanks for the mention of "challenge response scheme", I'll have a look into that :)

Comment: Don't store encrypted user passwords. You never need to know what the password is, so you shouldn't be able to find out what it is. Store salted, hashed passwords instead. See the [password storage cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @Quentin - That isn't entirely true. If a webserver is compromised and the authentication scheme doesn't use a challenge / response setup or something similar the server eventually has access to the unhashed, unsalted password. Even if it's just momentarily while the hash is generated. A clever hacker could easily alter a PHP script to store passwords in a permanent location and just wait for people to log in again.